# Output gives incorrect answer

Tags: c, nested

so I've been stuck here for a while, this code is to compute their salary using nested if.
the user will input their years in work and enter either 'B' for blue collar and 'W' for white collar job.
my code runs but it gives me 2 diff salary

for example:
if I enter 3 years of work and 'B'  (blue collar)
the salary should be 12,000 but in my code it prints 10,000 and 12,000

here's a little guide to avoid confusion:

<2 yrs and 'B' = 10,000

<2 yrs and 'W' = 20,000

<5 yrs and 'B' = 12,000

<5 yrs and 'W' = 40,000

5yrs+ and 'B' = 15,000

5yrs+ and 'W' = 75,000

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
char kind;
int years;

//input
printf("Enter years of work: ");
scanf("%d",&years);
printf("Enter kind of work: ");
scanf(" %c",&kind);

//condition
if(years<=1) {
    if(kind=='B')
        printf("Salary: 10,000");
        else 
            printf("Salary: 20,000");
}

if(years<=2 || years>=4) {
    if(kind=='B')
        printf("Salary: 12,000");
        else 
            printf("Salary: 40,000");
}

if(years>=5) {
    if(kind=='B')
        printf("Salary: 15,000");
        else 
            printf("Salary: 75,000");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `char kind; ... scanf("%s",&kind);` is bad.  How long a string do you want to save?  Please provide a long example.

Comment: `"%s"` is used to read a string. Use `" %c"` to read one character. The space character in `" %c"` is not a typo. You need that space character.

Comment: @user3386109 `scanf("%s",.... )`,  without a _width_ is worse than `gets()`.

Comment: when I use %c instead of %s, it skips the "enter kind of work" and proceeds to print the output

Comment: I'm not really sure why

Comment: so I tried to use %c with a space, I was able to input the kind of work, but it still gives two salary

Comment: You need to do `if (years < 2) { ... } else if (years < 5) { ... } else { ... }`. The condition `if (years <= 2 || years >= 4)` is true for any integer except 3. Note that `||` is the logical-OR operator, `&&` is the logical-AND operator.

Comment: Your `if` conditions are wonky and not mutually exclusive, so you get multiple outputs.  The first is OK; the second should probably read `else if (years >= 2 && years <= 4)`; the third should probably read `else` (or `else if (years >= 5)`).  Using `else` appropriately prevents multiple conditions matching and printing.

Comment: `scanf` should never be used for interactive input. If your textbook advocates it, find another one.

Answer (score 1):

ok so firstly you need to see that "kind" here is a char and not string, to make it a string you have to write

```
char kind[];
```

and you need to put "(string name here)" to compare a string and not '(string name here)', which is used to specify character.
anyways, it would be much more simpler and convenient if you just scan it as a char

```
 char kind;
 scanf(" %c",&kind);
```

second problem here is with the nested if case.
you need to put the {} after the if cases inside the nested if
for example:

```
if(years<2)
{
if(kind=='B')
   {
    printf("Salary: 10,000");
   }
    else 
        printf("Salary: 20,000");
 }
```

in c there is a default problem if you write

```
  "%c"
```

then the program will skip the input so please remember to write

```
  " %c"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to start my nested conditionals with the input with the most specific conditions first, sometimes lose statements can have some consequences if they are first. I moved it around a bit and added another check in the start and changed your years > 2 and years < 4 to years >= 2 and years <= 4, so we are a little more specific with what were trying to catch. I always looked at nested conditionals as falling down a ladder, and eventually the right spot "catches" you and you just got to make sure you get caught by the correct statement for sure. I tested this and it seems to work fine for me in my compiler, but I ran it in a few online and they seemed to throw a fit. Honestly no idea why, but C is weird sometimes.

Main point the way I prefer to do it when nesting conditionals, be as specific as humanly possible at the beginning, save the wider possibilities for the end. shoot for the stars, and land amongst the moon lol

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
char kind;
int years;

//input
printf("Enter years of work: ");
scanf("%d",&years);
printf("Enter kind of work: ");
scanf("%s",&kind);

//condition
// Start off with a check to rule out anything above 5
if ( years < 5 ) {
    // Add the or equal too signs, to help tighten the conditions
    if ( years <= 4 && years >= 2) {
        if ( kind == 'B' ) {
            printf("Salary: 12,000");
        }
        else {
            printf("Salary: 40,000");
        }
    }
    // This is the tricky one, so we nest it deeper. for some reason
    // this likes to get triggered allot, we could possibly just do years <= 1
    // to eliminate the number 2 entirely, since 2 is above
    else if ( years < 2 ) {
        if ( kind == 'B' ) {
            printf("Salary: 10,000");
        }
        else {
            printf("Salary: 20,000");
        }
    }
}
// Edited to ass the missing = for input = 5 that I forgot haha.
else if ( years >= 5 ) {
    if ( kind == 'B' ) {
        printf("Salary: 15,000");
    }
    else {
        printf("Salary: 75,000");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really think you should start with `if (years > 5) { … }` and then test `else if (years >= 2) { … } else { /* years < 2 */ … }`.  I'm not sure where `years == 5` is supposed to go, but make sure that base is covered — at the moment, your code does not print anything for that case.

Comment: Ohh your right that last (years > 5) was supposed to be (years >= 5), Funnily enough, I never actually tested 5 as input! It was caught up in numbers less than 5. For whatever reason I kept having issues with them making it to the wrong conditions. Thanks =)